# Batch am I piping correct?

Tags: batch-file

I have this code that shows all lines + empty line in a file:

```
findstr /R "^" "test.bat" | find /C /V ""
```

That works if I type it in cmd but if I start it in my Batch Skript I get this Error: *"FINDSTR:

no search string"*
This is how I use it in my Code:

```
FOR /f "tokens=1" %%f in ('findstr /R "^" "!BAT_[%Temp_Counter%]!" ^| find /C /V ""') do ( 
    set ALL_Counter_[%Temp_Counter%]=%%f
    )
```

It tried just the findstr line without FOR and with a test file like this but I still get the same error.

```
findstr /R "^" "test.bat" ^| find /C /V ""
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Here is my whole code section. the For loop in REM is how I did it before but that way i get errors with spaces in filenames (c:\desktop\test folder\test.bat)
Thats why I use the new method.

```
:SUB_CountingRows

REM ---------------COUNTING_ROWS------------------------START-------------------

ECHO  %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%_%Time% INFO START Counting Rows >> %PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%
set Temp_Counter=0

REM With empty lines?
IF "%COUNT_SPACE%"=="true" (
    goto LOOP3 ) else ( 
    goto LOOP2
    )

    :LOOP3
    echo on 
    ECHO  %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%_%Time% INFO Batchscript: !BAT_[%Temp_Counter%]! >> %PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%
    IF NOT "%Temp_Counter%"=="%Bat_Count%" (

        FOR /f "tokens=1" %%f in ('findstr /R "^" "!BAT_[%Temp_Counter%]!" ^| find /C /V ""') do ( 
            set ALL_Counter_[%Temp_Counter%]=%%f
            )
            echo !ALL_Counter_[%Temp_Counter%]!



        REM FOR /f "tokens=3" %%f in ('find /c /v "" "!BAT_[%Temp_Counter%]!"') do ( 
            REM set ALL_Counter_[%Temp_Counter%]=%%f
            REM )

        FOR /f "tokens=1 delims=     " %%a in (!BAT_[%Temp_Counter%]!) DO (
            set result=false

            IF /i "%%a"=="REM" (
                set result=true
                )
            IF /i "%%a"=="@REM" (
                set result=true
                )
            IF "!result!"=="true" (
                set /a REM_Counter_[%Temp_Counter%]=!REM_Counter_[%Temp_Counter%]!+1
                )
            )

            set /a Temp_Counter=%Temp_Counter%+1    
            GOTO LOOP3
        )
    ECHO  %DATE:~-4%%DATE:~-7,2%%DATE:~-10,2%_%Time% INFO STOP Counting Rows >> %PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%
    REM ---------------COUNTING_ROWS------------------------END-----------------
    GOTO :eof
```

Comment: `findstr` seems to have a problems to process files that contain certain characters. Use `type "t.bat" | find /C /V ""`, which does exactly the same.

Comment: @Stephan - FINDSTR has problems with some characters within arguments, but it does not have problems with any  characters within the file content.

Comment: Works happily for me on Win10. Perhaps we need to se the filenames being processed.

Comment: I am getting the same as @Magoo let's see some file names

Comment: PS!! In the last string, remove escape ^ before | as it is not in a for loop. if is impossible to get the exact same error as in the for loop, different errors, but not the same.

Comment: I see no need for both `FindStr` and `Find` inside those parentheses. Given the `For` loop you've used, and delayed expansion having been enabled, why could you not just reduce it to, `For /F %%A In ('"Find /C /V ""<"!BAT_[%Temp_Counter%]!""') Do Set "ALL_Counter_[%Temp_Counter%]=%%A"`? _**Note:** this answer was based on your question before you added all of your code_.

Comment: Because the Results I get are like this `---------- TEST.BAT: 95`. Like I said with filenames without a space in them i can just take the third token (like I did in the commented out
 FOR loop) but if there is a space in the filename I can't.

Comment: Try my code, I have already catered for that scenario, it does not output that!

Comment: @dbenham hrrm - I copy-pasted the code line (with `^|`) and was missleaded by the errormessages.`:/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of your supplied code with a few corrections for your delayed expansion errors. *(I'm not sure if I've caught them all, and haven't checked your code for other problems, other than the change I mentioned in my comment)*

```bat
:SUB_CountingRows
Rem ---------------COUNTING_ROWS------------------------START-------------------
(Echo  !DATE:~-4!!DATE:~-7,2!!DATE:~-10,2!_!Time! INFO START Counting Rows)>>"%PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%"
Set "Temp_Counter=0"
If /I Not "%COUNT_SPACE%"=="true" GoTo LOOP2

:LOOP3
Call Set "B_T_C=%%BAT_[!Temp_Counter!]%%"
(ECHO  !DATE:~-4!!DATE:~-7,2!!DATE:~-10,2!_!Time! INFO Batchscript: !B_T_C!)>>"%PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%"
If Not "!Temp_Counter!"=="%Bat_Count%" (
    For /F "Delims=" %%f In ('"Find /C /V ""<"!B_T_C!""') Do Set "ALL_Counter_[!Temp_Counter!]=%%f"
    Call Echo %%ALL_Counter_[!Temp_Counter!]%%
    For /F "UsebackQ Delims=     " %%a In ("!B_T_C!") Do (Set "result=false"
        If /I "%%a"=="REM" Set "result=true"
        If /I "%%a"=="@REM" Set "result=true"
        If "!result!"=="true" Set /A REM_Counter_[!Temp_Counter!] +=1
    )
    Set /A Temp_Counter +=1 
    GoTo LOOP3
)

(ECHO  !DATE:~-4!!DATE:~-7,2!!DATE:~-10,2!_!Time! INFO STOP Counting Rows)>>"%PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%"
Rem ---------------COUNTING_ROWS------------------------END---------------------
GoTo :EOF
```

Comment: Sry, for the long wait. Counting all lines works fine now, but now it splits !B_T_C! in the second FOR loop "    `For /F "Tokens=1 Delims=     " %%a In (!B_T_C!) Do (Set "result=false"
        If /I "%%a"=="REM" Set "result=true"
        If /I "%%a"=="@REM" Set "result=true"
        If "!result!"=="true" Set /A REM_Counter_[!Temp_Counter!] +=1
    )`

Comment: everything works now, but can you explain why you use Call here? `Call Set "B_T_C=%%BAT_[!Temp_Counter!]%%"` and here `Call Echo %%ALL_Counter_[!Temp_Counter!]%%` and why do you put the %ALL_Counter_[!Temp_Counter!]% in two extra % ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it works now I just use the code from @Compo and add usebackQ and "" in the For Loop.

```
:SUB_CountingRows
Rem ---------------COUNTING_ROWS------------------------START-------------------
(Echo  !DATE:~-4!!DATE:~-7,2!!DATE:~-10,2!_!Time! INFO START Counting Rows)>>"%PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%"
Set "Temp_Counter=0"
If /I Not "%COUNT_SPACE%"=="true" GoTo LOOP2

:LOOP3
Call Set "B_T_C=%%BAT_[!Temp_Counter!]%%"
(ECHO  !DATE:~-4!!DATE:~-7,2!!DATE:~-10,2!_!Time! INFO Batchscript: !B_T_C!)>>"%PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%"
If Not "!Temp_Counter!"=="%Bat_Count%" (
    For /F %%f In ('"Find /C /V ""<"!B_T_C!""') Do Set "ALL_Counter_[!Temp_Counter!]=%%f"
    Call Echo %%ALL_Counter_[!Temp_Counter!]%%
    For /F "usebackq Tokens=1 Delims=     " %%a In ("!B_T_C!") Do (Set "result=false"
        If /I "%%a"=="REM" Set "result=true"
        If /I "%%a"=="@REM" Set "result=true"
        If "!result!"=="true" Set /A REM_Counter_[!Temp_Counter!] +=1
    )
    Set /A Temp_Counter +=1 
    GoTo LOOP3
)

(ECHO  !DATE:~-4!!DATE:~-7,2!!DATE:~-10,2!_!Time! INFO STOP Counting Rows)>>"%PATH_LOGDATEI%\%LOGFILE_NAME%"
Rem ---------------COUNTING_ROWS------------------------END---------------------
GoTo :EOF
```